# How to compare two user from relationship in views

Tags: views

I have a view to display the contents that a user bookmarked.

Here we have three users: the author of the content (uid from a relationship), the viewed user (uid from arguments), the logged-in user.

I would like to show only the contents that were flagged by but not created by the viewed user, how can I achieve this? I can only find a way to filter by the logged-in user.

Comment: how is this a comparison???

Comment: do relationship for this view with flag you want, and active the checkbox flagged

Comment: Sounds like you need [Views arguments in filters](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472)